# Using "to be sure" as to express it in an opposite way

Tags: grammar, usage

The passage goes,

> Some observers maintain that far from being a neutral judge of constitutional law, the supreme court has been a highly politicized institution from its beginning. It has focused on protecting the economic interests of the elites rather than the less powerful or the disadvantaged. This bias became readily apparent in the second half of the nineteenth century, when the Court issued a lot of decisions granting industrial corporations personhood rights and freedom from undue governmental interference in their operations. **To be sure,** the Court has issued many important rulings over the years - rulings upholding equality of opportunity and the civil rights of everyday Americans. Its landmark 1954 decision in *Brown Board of Education*, for instance, ended racial separation in public schools. However, some maintain that such rulings have done little to alter the underlying conditions of class inequality in the US. Edward S. Greenberg has argued that, the principal objectives of the Court and the federal court system at large have been to assure that those who own the main economic assets of society are secure in their control, use, and enjoyment of such assets.

What I am curious about is that I've seen using using words like **Certainly, Of course or Yet** in the place where **To be sure** is currently at, however, never seen using "to be sure".

I can see that the author is trying to say "Of course the Court did issue some important rulings for those disadvantaged, however, overall the rulings were too focused for those advantaged, and even the "important rulings" weren't as effective as possible. But, it seems to odd for me to used "To be sure" in such place.

Is **to be sure** also used to put emphasis on what the author is trying to say?

Comment: Yes, _to be sure_ can be used in the same way as _of course, certainly_ etc.in a context like this.

Comment: I think "To be sure" here more directly says "admittedly" than the other alternatives you listed in your question